# Defining class attribute with scope from method

Tags: php, class

I try to create attributes within a class using a method. It is possible to create an attribute, but how can I add a scope to the attributes? For example i want wachtwoord(password) to be private, but firstname to be public.

**Current code**

```
class UserEntity extends Entity{

/**
 * UserEntities constructor.
 */
public function __construct($user_id){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->loadDatabase();
    $this->get($user_id);
}

/**
 *  Get user form database
 *
 *  @param $user_id
 */
private function get($user_id){

    $prepare = $this->database->prepare("
        select * from gebruiker where gebruikerid = :user_id;
    ");

    $prepare->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id);
    $prepare->execute();
    $result =  $prepare->fetch($this->fetchMethod);

    foreach($result as $key => $value){
        $this->{$key} = $value;
    }
}
```

**Result (Print_r)**

```
UserEntity Object
```

(
    [database:protected] => PDO Object
        (
        )

```
[gebruikerid] => test_val
[0] => test_val
[voornaam] => test_val
[1] => test_val
[achternaam] => test_val
[2] => test_val
[email] => test_val
[3] => test_val
[rol] => test_val
[4] => test_val
[wachtwoord] => test_val
[5] => test_val
[laatstelogin] => test_val
[6] => test_val
[status] => test_val
[7] => test_val
[registratiedatum] => test_val
[8] => test_val
[afbeeldingurl] => test_val
[9] => test_val
[initialen] => test_val
[10] => test_val
[geboortedatum] => test_val
[11] => test_val
[bsn] => test_val
[12] => test_val
[laatstonline] => test_val
[13] => test_val
```

)

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for buggy result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to declare the properties in advance:

```
class UserEntity extends Entity {

    private $wachtwoord;
    public $firstname;

    ...
}
```

Dynamically added properties are always public.